# How to "safely" cast to void** without warning?

Tags: c++, casting

I am creating a simple game using SDL. And I came to a point where I needed to use the SDL_LockTexture function, so I wrote the following code.

```
uint8_t* pixels = nullptr;
int pitch = 0;
SDL_LockTexture(textures[texture_index], nullptr, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&pixels), &pitch);
```

However, clang-tidy warned me not to use reinterpret_cast. So I tried replacing it with static_cast, but static_cast gave me a compile error. The code itself works fine, but the warning is quite annoying. How can I safely cast to void** in C++ style?

Comment: Use a temporary variable of type `void*`, then pass a pointer to it. Then no explicit conversion (a.k.a. a cast) is needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a `void* vpixels`.  Pass a pointer to that to the function.

Then static cast the `void*` to a pixel pointer type.

You can write a helper that does this for you:

```
template<class T>
struct out_ptr {
  // could be private, I'm just being pithy.  Also, could block
  // copy/move, they aren't sane.
  T** out;
  void* temp = nullptr;

  // You construct an out_ptr with an lvalue of the pointer
  // you want to write to.  I chose this over `T**` because
  // we require it to be a valid reference, and `out_ptr` seems
  // to indicate writing strongly enough.
  out_ptr(T*& p) : out(&p) {}

  // implicit cast to void**, so we can use this where SDL
  // supports an out-pointer parameter.  It is rvalue qualified,
  // as I do not expect out_ptrs to live beyond temporary (and
  // don't really work if you do that, honestly).
  operator void**() && {
    return &temp;
  }

  // we write to the pointer we are constructed with when we are
  // destroyed.  If you use this as intended, this happens at the
  // end of the full-expression with the function call where we
  // populated &temp with the data we want.
  ~out_ptr() {
    *out = static_cast<T*>(temp);
  }
};
```

use:

```
SDL_LockTexture(textures[texture_index], nullptr, out_ptr{pixels}, &pitch);
```

This relies on CTAD: without it you'll want a helper function instead of directly calling the constructor.